# Problem running single-node job on computing cluster in conda environment for all processors in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, conda, cluster-computing

I am trying to run a single-node job on my university computing cluster, submitted via qsub, within a conda environment "myenv". As soon as I start my parallelization within my R script, the different processors start with the base environment instead of with "myenv". A test parallelization works perfectly within the base environment, so the issue is starting "myenv" for all processors. The environment "myenv" also works well for the first processor.

I submit the following bash script via qsub (1 node with 20 processors):

```
source /mypath/conda.sh
conda activate myenv
Rscript myscript.R
```

I am using a conda environment with the latest R-version and specific packages. The base environment on the cluster has an extremely outdated R-version which is not compatible with the packages that I need (e.g. raster). (Updating the base environment on the cluster is not possible, according to IT).

This is my R-script:

```
require(raster)
require(doSNOW)

r1 <- raster("raster1.tif") # works perfectly (conda environment is activated here)

nc = 19
cl = makeSOCKcluster(nc)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

foreach(f=1:19)  %dopar% {

  require(raster) # does not work (conda environment is not activated here)
  # (error: there is no package called raster)

  r2 <- raster("raster2.tif")

}
```

I have tried (none of them worked for me):

1. `foreach(f=1:19, .packages = c("raster"))  %dopar% {...}`
2. to load the conda environment with a system call (via `sytem2` in R) within the loop
3. the future package for a parallel for-loop via `%dofuture%`
4. running the job in the old base-R installation and loading packages from a package folder via `.libPaths("mypath")`: works with some packages, but not other packages which are incompatible with the old base-R version

Could any one help, please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following shell script that uses MPI. This is more-less equivalent to your socket cluster, except that it uses MPI, which is more common on HPC clusters. It will simply run 19 copies of your code. Your `module load` names and requirements may vary on your cluster. You will also need to `install.packages("pbdMPI")` in a login-node R session before running this.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS <your-pbs-requests>
#PBS ...

module load conda
module load OpenMPI
module load r

source /mypath/conda.sh
conda activate myenv
mpirun -n 19 Rscript myscript.R
```

And R script, myscript.R:

```
library(raster)
library(pbdMPI)
rank = comm.rank()

# you probably need to form file names from ranks
filename = paste0("raster", rank, ".tif")
r <- raster(filename)

# rest of your code
```

The shell script runs 19 copies of the R code, where the instance ranks will be 0 to 18, each reading a different file. The script will work for any number of instances, as long as you request the resources in the shell script.

This simplifies your R code. If you need to combine the results of the 19 copies, consider `allreduce()` and `allgather()` in **pbdMPI**. This approach is called single-program multiple-data (SPMD), which is more general and extensible than the manager-workers style of doSNOW.

Comment: Also add a `finalize()` at the end of your R code for a graceful exit by MPI.